# Unable to receive data from front-end to back-end

Tags: python, html, ajax

Data is not being sent  from front end  to back end and im using Html and ajax for the front end and linking up part

//signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <script src= "../static/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src= "../static/sha1.min.js"></script>
     <script src = "../static/sha1.js"></script>
     <script>
     $(function(){
            $('.btnblock').click(function(){
                      var user = $('#inputUsername').val();
                      var pass = sha1($('#inputPassword').val());
                      //alert(pass);
                      //alert(JSON.stringify({username : user, password : pass}))
                      $.ajax({
                                   url : 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users',
                                   data : JSON.stringify({username : user, password : pass}),
                                   type : 'POST',
                                   method : 'post',
                                   ContentType : 'text/plain',
                                   dataType: 'json',
                                   success: function(response){
                                                   alert(response);
                                   },
                                   error: function(error){
                                                   alert(error);
                                   }
                      });
              });
     });
     </script>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <center>
        <h1> Add user. </h1>
    </center>
</head>

<body background="{{ url_for('static', filename='home/background.jpeg')}}">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="btnblock" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
     </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the code which process these requests from the frontend is:

```
def addUser():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        ##print(request._dict_)
        print("Receiving data....")
        data = request.data.decode()
        print(data)
```

the problem here is what ever credentials  and data added in the front-end isn't getting processed in the back-end, print(request.data) returns empty and does not return the added data each time and i did try debugging it a few times and googling what would the mistake be but still got no progress , Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Is `request.data` empty too?

Comment: yes request.data returns empty

Comment: Try to send data without `JSON.stringify()` or wrap into an object: `{data: JSON.stringify({username : user, password : pass})}`